# Paypal express checkout get receipt id in response

Tags: paypal

Is there a way I can get paypal receipt id in response when using paypal express checkout.

I do get the transaction id but i need receipt id. Paypal is sending receipt id to customer via mail but i need it in API response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [Reach out to PayPal about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296339/reach-out-to-paypal-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Only way to get Receipt ID, you have to call the `GetTransactionDetails` api and can get receipt id from here.

Docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just tried to get transaction detail from transaction id, but it does not display receipt id. It gives many data in response but no receipt id.

Comment: If you actually look at the documentation he linked to, though, it does show RECEIPTID would be returned by this API.  If you're not getting it included in the response then the transaction must simply not have one.  If I remember correctly, a receipt_id is only included in a transaction if a credit card was used as the funding source during PayPal checkout.  If PayPal/bank funds were used there would be no receipt ID.